# laravel route any page in a folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I am trying to route any blade file that are inside a folder called "pages" (application/views/pages/page.blade.php)

```
$path = '/pages/'.$anyname.'.blade.php';
Route::get('file/(:all)', function($path){});
```

how should change the $anyname which will enable to retrieve any blade file?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using scandir method.

```
$dir = path('app').'/views/pages/';
$pages = scandir($dir);
unset($pages[array_search('.', $pages)]);
unset($pages[array_search('..', $pages)]);

for($i = 2; $i <count($pages)+2; $i++){
    //print_r($pages[$i]);
    $temp = str_replace('.blade.php', '', $pages[$i]);

    Route::get($temp, function(){
        //return View::('index');
        return 'asd';
    });
}
```